# Angular Kendo UI Disable Options In DropDown

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to disable options in kendo drop down?
Or hide them from list?
In html it is:

```
<select>
  <option value="volv" [disabled]="">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saa">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">V</option>
</select>
```

How can I do I it in Kendo DropDown?

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
            <kendo-combobox
                [data]="listItems"
                [textField]="'text'"
                [valueField]="'value'"
                [value]="selectedValue"
                [valuePrimitive]="true">
                <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                    <span class="template">{{ dataItem.value }}</span> {{ 
                       dataItem.text }}
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-combobox>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can check kendo dropdownlist disable option, it may work with this. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/how-to/selection/disable-items-for-selection

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see they have something for it in their documentation for Kendo UI for Angular. I'd suggest to filter out the elements you want to be 'disabled'. You can do with any method you like. I prefer lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Comment: The disable is needed for selecting options by code not by user.
I need the options to be existing in list but not for user selection..

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution by Kendo.
Can solve it by this ways:

```
    <kendo-combobox (valueChange)="valueChange($event);" [placeholder]="'xxx" [data]="data"  [textField]="'Value'" [valueField]="'Value'" >
  <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    <button class="template"  [disabled]="!dataItem.Max" >{{dataItem.Value}}</button>
  </ng-template>
 </kendo-combobox>
```

or:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: ['.template { display: inline-block; background: #333; color: #fff; border-radius: 50%; width: 18px; height: 18px; text-align: center; } '],
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <kendo-combobox
            [data]="listItems"
            [textField]="'text'"
            [valueField]="'value'"
            [value]="selectedValue"
            [valuePrimitive]="true"
            (open)="onOpen($event)"
        >
            <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                <button>{{ dataItem.text }}</button>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-combobox>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
  .disabled {
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:0.6;         

  }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
    public listItems: Array<{ text: string, value: number }> = [
        { text: "Small", value: 1 },
        { text: "Medium", value: 2 },
        { text: "Large", value: 3 }
    ];

    public selectedValue;

    onValChange(e){

    }
    onOpen(){
      let liArr

      setTimeout(()=>{
        liArr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("k-item"))
        liArr.forEach(el => {
          if(el.innerText.indexOf('Small') != -1){
            el.classList.add("disabled")
          }
      })
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,

The following example demonstrates how to disable specific list options by using the ***itemDisabled*** property when the DropDownList is bound to complex data.

https://stackblitz.com/run

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/disabled-items/

Comment: is it possible to execute itemDisabled dynamically?